# PHP if else not working

Tags: php, if-statement

Why this if is not working ? Any idea anyone.. I know there is something minor but wasted more than half an hour already.

```
                <?php if(1){ ?>
              <?php
                    echo "
                      <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">
                        <li><a href=\"#\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#loginModal\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Post</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      " ; 
             }?>
             <?php else{ ?>
                <?php
                  echo "
                      <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">
                        <li><a href=\"#\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#loginModal\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Post</a></li>
                      </ul> 
                      ";                
             }?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? Please be more specific. Both codes inside the if else looks the same, and why is the if(1) ? what condition that you wanted to check?

Comment: What is `if(1)` supposed to be?

Comment: `Why this if is not working` explain it. What's the desired output ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php
    if(1){ 
        echo "
            <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">
                  <li><a href=\"#\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#loginModal\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Post</a></li>
            </ul>
              " ; 
   }
   else{
       echo "
           <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">
                 <li><a href=\"#\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#loginModal\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Post</a></li>
           </ul> 
             ";                
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple php opening and closing tags that are redundant.

As whole code block is in php you need only one opening and one closing

```
<?php

if (1)
    {
    echo "
            <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">
            <li><a href=\"#\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#loginModal\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Post</a></li>
            </ul>
            ";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "
            <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">
            <li><a href=\"#\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#loginModal\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Post</a></li>
            </ul> 
            ";
}

?>
```

Your original code is not working because of the multiple php tags, if block is getting ended inappropriately thus at else it is showing as unexpected token

See the image below

[image]

Comment: I have 2 add on questions
1. What if I need multiple open and close like php if than some html and else than somehtml and some php again, html and so on.. ?
2.I don't get the mistake in original code except for redundancy

Comment: By first question you mean that, to show some html on `if` condition and some other html on `else` condition is it so??

Comment: No a series of html part than php than html.. point is can I have multiple open close php tags inside an id or an else?

Comment: yes you can use multiple php code blocks inside html like `<html>...</html>  <?php ... ?>  <html>...</html>  <?php ... ?>` required that proper opening and closing tags are there.